# Помогите разобрать шаги действия программы

Tags: javascript

2 раза вызывается функция getJSONP( "ph.php", call); вследствие чего создаются 2 элемента скрипт - которые выполняются в функции getJSONP.eee. Функция getJSONP.eee перезаписывается. Значит оба элемента скрипт будут выполнять одну функцию getJSONP.eee - в которой переменная script является последим тегом скрипт.

Вопрос: Почему при втором вызове функция alert(script); говорит что элемент есть, хотя он был удалён при первом вызове. И выходит ошибка TypeError: script.parentNode is null

```js
function call(a) {
  alert(a);
}
function getJSONP(url, callback) {
        url += "?jsonp=getJSONP.eee";

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    alert(7);
    getJSONP.eee = function(response) {
        script.title="two"; // Для отслеживания тег взаимодейстия
        alert(document.getElementsByTagName("script").length); // Сколько всего тегов
    callback(response); // Результат
    alert(script); // Проверить на наличие тега
    script.parentNode.removeChild(script); // Удалить тег
    alert(script); // Проверить на наличие тега. Почему есть?
    };

   
    script.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    if(t==1) script.title="one"; // Для отслеживания тег взаимодейстия
}
var t = 1;
getJSONP( "ph.php", call);
getJSONP( "ph.php", call); // При этом getJSONP.eee - перезаписывается
```

```js
<?php

$seq = array("foo", "bar", "baz", "blong");
$json = json_encode($seq);

echo $_GET['jsonp'].'('.$json.')';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ну вот как-то так, что ли.**

```
function call(a) {
  alert(a);
}
function getJSONP(url, callback) {
        url += "?jsonp=getJSONP.eee";

    var script = document.createElement("script");
//   alert(7);
//    getJSONP.eee = function(response) {
        script.eee = function(){
//          script.title="two"; /* Для отслеживания тег взаимодействия*/
            alert(scope_In_getJSONP.length); /* Сколько всего тегов cделала функция getJSONP */
//          callback(response); // Результат
            callback(this); /* this указывает на контекст вызова */
            alert(script); /* Проверить на наличие тега // на этом этапе
 вы обращаетесь к объекту который участвовать в DOM модель*/
            alert(script.parentNode); /* имеет все свойства и методы для элементов участвующих в DOM модели*/
            script.parentNode.removeChild(script); // Удалить тег
            scope_In_getJSONP.splice(script.markerScope, 1) /* удаляем из скопа элементов созданных функцией getJSONP */
            alert(script); /* Проверить на наличие тега. Почему есть?*/
            alert(script.parentNode); /* теперь вы обращаетесь к шаблону
у которого нет связи с DOM модель*/
            alert(scope_In_getJSONP.length); /*длина скопа элементов созданных функцией getJSONP уменьшелась*/
        };


        script.src = url;
        scope_In_getJSONP.push(document.body.appendChild(script)); /*
 создаем узел в DOM модели и результат помещаем в массив элементов
 созданных функцией getJSONP*/
        script.markerScope = scope_In_getJSONP.length-1 /* маркер 
идентификатор для быстрого поиска элементов при удалении */
    if(t==1) script.title="one"; /* Для отслеживания тег взаимодействия
 <<< ???? */
}
var t = 1;
var scope_In_getJSONP = [];
getJSONP( "ph.php", call);
getJSONP( "ph.php", call); /* При этом getJSONP.eee - перезаписывается*/
scope_In_getJSONP[0].eee() //
```